# Angular library include external library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I am trying to include several dependencies in my library (ex. dashjs, leaflet, ...).

I know how to include it in a standard Angular project. Add dependencies to package.json and add each external library to the "script" tag in my angular.json file.

When creating an Angular library there is no angular.json file. Sadly the Angular documentation doesn't help either. Someone already figured out how to do it and can share details about it?

Comment: Yes, the answer one doesn't need anything special.

Answer (score -1):

Your library has its own package.json, where you can specify its dependencies:

```
{
    "name": "myPackage",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "My Package.",
    "author": "Me",
    "dependencies": {
        "myDep": "1.1"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    }
}
```

Check out this tutorial:
https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#peer-dependencies

Comment: Thanks but the question was about how to include external scripts into the library.